# Create new line in document write (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, newline, line-breaks

How do I make all of the items inside document.get on new lines? I've tried `br/` and `\n`. Neither of which work. They either cause the JavaScript to run incorrectly or don't create new lines. I know I can put each in its own paragraph element but for my purposes I have to have it all in one paragraph element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var     firstString =  prompt(" Enter the first number ", "");
    var     secondString = prompt(" Enter the second number ", "");
    var     num1 = parseFloat(firstString);
    var     num2 = parseFloat(secondString);

    var addition = num1 + num2;         //  Addition of num1 and num2
    var subtraction = num1 - num2;      //  Subtraction of num1 and num2
    var multiplication = num1 * num2;   //  Multiplication of num1 and num2
    var division = num1 / num2          //  Division of num1 and num2

    //These are the ones I'm trying to get to appear on separate lines

    document.write (
        "<p> First Value Entered: " + num1 + \n
        "Second Value Entered: " + num2 + \n
        "Sum: " + addition + \n
        "Difference: " + subtraction + \n
        "Product: " + multiplication + \n
        "Quotient: " + division + "</p>"
    );
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, it's part of an ancient JS API from before we had DOM manipulation functions and should never be used (and it's dangerous: [it really doesn't do what you think it does](http://webreflection.blogspot.ca/2009/12/documentwriteshenanigans.html)). Create your stuff with `document.createElement`, set their content with `.textContent=...` (not `.innerHTML`, because that's just more DOM content, create it as such) and then add it to the DOM with `document.body.appendChild(...)` / `element.appendChild(...)`

Comment: Yes, I know, this was the criteria of the assignment -_-

Comment: you need to talk to whoever assigned that. This is not proper HTML+JS, and hasn't been for years now.

Comment: Why not use the <pre>The text here\nMore text</pre>?

Answer (score 6):

Put `\n` in quotes, like so: `"\n"`, and don't forget to put plus signs after them too. It's one big concatenated string.

ETA: As mentioned in the other answer, pure HTML doesn't support newlines, so use `<br>`!

Comment: it's trying to evaluate `\n` like a variable or a keyword, you want a string.

Comment: and no, it would render as a newline, if you really wanted to render `\n` you'd have to escape the slash like so: `"\\n"`

Comment: Well, you're right, it's rendered when escaped only, but `\n` can be seen in the `outer/innerHTML` only, it doesn't create a new-line to the page.

Comment: ah, indeed. I'm used to updating fields and other elements that do support it. In pure HTML, `<br>`'s your solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

- quote all your string literals
- put a `+` between *each* pair of strings you want to concatenate
- use a `<br>` element instead of a literal new line (since a new line in HTML doesn't cause a line break to be rendered)

Such:

```
"Second Value Entered: " + num2 + "<br>" +
```

That said, this looks more like a job for `dl`/`dt`/`dd` than a paragraph with line breaks in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- JavaScript Arith - Oct. 22, 1918 -->

var name = prompt("Hello and Welcome! I'm Chip. We're going to play a little math game. What's your name?", "");

    alert("Hello, " + name + ". Please enter a number for each prompt. Please, do not use 0 for either number.")

    var answer, sum, difference, product, quotient, power = -1; // Initialize 
    // Input - Prompt for the numbers

    // Processing - the preparation for number crunching        

    // Make sure the values are numeric.var first = Number(prompt("Enter the first number", ""));       
    var first = Number(prompt("Enter the first number", ""));
    var second = Number(prompt("Enter the second number", ""));

    // Output - results 
    // Feedback - later for errors, e.g., 0, letters, etc.
    document.write(name + ", the numbers chosen were: " + first + " and " + second);

    document.write(".<br>The results are shown below.<ul>");

    var sum = first + second;
    document.write("<li>Sum: " + sum + "</li>"); // ad d

    var difference = first - second;
    document.write("<li>Difference: " + difference + "</li>"); // subtract
    /*
    M, S and D. For positive arguments M and S holds:
    The minuend (M) is the first number in a subtraction; the number from which another number (the Subtrahend) is to be subtracted.
    The subtrahend (s) is the number that is being subtracted from the minuend.
    Minuend.
    Example: in 8 − 3 = 5, 8 is the minuend (M). 3 is the subtrahend (S). 5 is the difference (D).
    If the minuend is larger than the subtrahend, the difference D is positive.
    If the minuend is smaller than the subtrahend, the difference D is negative.
    In any case, if minuend and subtrahend are equal, the difference D = 0.
    */

    var product = first * second;
    document.write("<li>Product: " + product + "</li>");    // multiply
    /* factors */

    var quotient = first / second;
    document.write("<li>Quotient: " + quotient + "</li>");  // divide
    /*
    Division shows the relationship between the dividend, divisor, quotient and remainder. The number which we divide (before  the '/' operator) is called the 'dividend.' The number by which we divide (after the '/' operator)is called the 'divisor.' The result obtained is called the 'quotient.'
    */

    var power = first ** second;
    document.write("<li>Power: " + power + "</li>");    // exponentiation

    document.write("</ul>Thanks, " + name + ". Have a Nice Day!");
```

Comment: Put the above in <script> </script>  tags in html file. Uses <ul> - unordered list. When you run it the results are displayed w/ the #s chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("\n");

document.write("<br>");
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 function breakline()
       {
            document.write("Hi?<br> nice shirt");
            // "<br>" use in document.write
         
            alert("Hi? \n nice shirt");
            // '/n' use in alert 
       }
       
       breakline();
```

Comment: Can you explain why your answer solves the question?